# Laravel 5.2 Validation working but $errors variable is empty

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I've look all around SO for similar questions and tried every answers. The validator checks the rules and redirects fine. But the $errors variable is still empty in my views.

Controller:

```
public function postSlidesAdd(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'priority' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        //insert to db and redirect back
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/admin/slides/add', [
        'uses' => 'SitesController@postSlidesAdd',
        'as' => 'admin.slides.add'
    ]);
});
```

View:

```
<div class="">
            @if(count($errors)>0))
                <ul>
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{$error}}</li>

                    @endforeach
                </ul>

            @endif
        </div>
```

I think I'm missing something small and important, please help.
I'm using Laravel 5.2.29

UPDATE:
If this is of any help; In my controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        dd($validator->errors());
        return back()->withErrors($validator);
    }
```

This dumps an array 'messages' and inside is another array containing [input names => error messages]. I think this is the array to be sent to the views, but it doesn't get through. Help please what Am I doin wrong.

Comment: I think it's `$validator->message()`?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but message() method does not exist in the validator;

Comment: ow. try to make it `messages()`

Comment: messages method still not found in class sir.

Answer (score 5):

In `app\Http\Kernel.php` move `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` from the 'web' `$middlewareGroups` to `$middleware`

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with your view file; you have an extra parenthesis. Try changing this:

```
@if(count($errors)>0))
```

To this:

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
```

Also, in your controller, try changing:

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
```

To this:

```
return back()->withErrors($validator);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I updated it and still no data in $errors.

Comment: Hi Sir, i updated it. still empty. If this of any help; in my controller:
if ($validator->fails()) {
            dd($validator->errors());
            return back()->withErrors($validator);
        }
It returns an array of 'messages' inside is another array with the [input names => error messages].

Comment: Try running `{{ dd($errors) }}` before the if statement in your view

Comment: i put it inside @if(isset($errors)) otherwise the view won't load.

It returned ViewErrorBag {#182 ▼
  #bags: []
} an empty array

Comment: Are you sure valid errors are occurring? What form fields are you submitting with? What does `dd($request->all())` print out in your controller?

Comment: I have no problem with form or the validation itself, I think the problem is controller not posting into the $errors that could be accessed in views. dd($request->all()) returns array names of my inputs with values including the _token.